# Write a hex string as binary data in Python

Tags: python, hex

I have a string of data like `FF0000FF` and I want to write that to a file as raw 8-bit bytes `11111111 00000000 00000000 11111111`.  However, I seem to end up getting way to much data `FF` turns into `FF 00 00 00` when using `struct.pack` or I get a literal ASCII version of the 0's and 1's.

How can I simply take a string of hex and write that as binary, so when viewed in a hex-editor, you see the same hex string?

Comment: Do you want to write out a *string representation* of the binary, or write out the actual numeric value?

Comment: I want to write out the binary representation of hex pairs as 8-bit values in binary format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

> **binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)**
>   Return the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string hexstr.
>   This function is the inverse of b2a_hex(). hexstr must contain
>   an even number of hexadecimal digits (which can be upper or lower
>   case), otherwise a TypeError is raised.

```
import binascii
hexstr = 'FF0000FF'
binstr = binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `bytes`'s `hex` and `fromhex` like this:

```
>>> ss = '7e7e303035f8350d013d0a'
>>> bytes.fromhex(ss)
b'~~005\xf85\r\x01=\n'
>>> bb = bytes.fromhex(ss)
>>> bytes.hex(bb)
'7e7e303035f8350d013d0a'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x you can just use the b prefix in front of modified form of the string, and then write it out to a binary file like so:

```
hex_as_bytes = b"\xFF\x00\x00\xFF"
with open("myFileName", "wb") as f: f.write(hex_as_bytes)
```

Comment: sorry I omitted the hex escapes. I fixed it now